# Rust enum implement += 1

Tags: rust

I try to write Minesweeper
I have enum with status of cell and trying to write function to recognize how much mines around it.

```
enum CellStatus {
  CLOSED,  
  MINED,
  FLAGED,
  OPENED,
  ONE,
  TWO,
  THREE,
  FOUR,
  FIVE,
  SIX,
  SEVEN,
  EIGHT
}

if mine_area[i+1][j+1] == CellStatus::MINED {
        mine_area[i][j] += 1;
}
```

This is what compiler advice me:

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `CellStatus`
   --> src/main.rs:25:9
    |
25  |         mine_area[i][j] += 1;
    |         ---------------^^^^^
    |         |
    |         cannot use `+=` on type `CellStatus`
    |
note: an implementation of `AddAssign<_>` might be missing for `CellStatus`
   --> src/main.rs:126:1
    |
126 | enum CellStatus {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ must implement `AddAssign<_>`
note: the following trait must be implemented
```

On offical [AddAssign](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) it is example for Point, and it struct not enum.

BrownieInMotion advised me to use u8 in Opened, it's really helpful, but not a solution to a problem.

Comment: It does not matter if it is a struct or enum. It is implemented the same way for both. Also you will likely save yourself the headache if you use an integer type for the mine count instead of separate enum variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it correct:

```
impl AddAssign for Status {
  fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Self) {
    *self = match *self {
      Status::Opened(count) => match other {
        Status::Opened(count2) => Status::Opened(count + count2),
        _ => other,
      },
      _ => other
    }
  }
}
```

My final implementation is:

```
use std::ops::AddAssign;

fn main() {
  let width:u16 = 5;
  let heigh:u16 = 5;

  let mut game_area = vec![vec![Status::Closed; width.into()]; heigh.into()];

  game_area[1][1] = Status::Opened(0);
  game_area[1][1] += Status::Opened(1);
  game_area[1][1] += Status::Opened(1);
  game_area[1][1] += Status::Opened(1);

  println!("{}", game_area[1][1].as_str());
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Status {
  Closed,
  Flagged,
  Mined,
  Opened(u8),
}

const MINE_CHAR: [&str; 9] = ["", "1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣", "5️⃣", "6️⃣", "7️⃣", "8️⃣"];

impl Status {
  pub fn as_str(&self) -> String {
    match self {
      Status::Mined => "".to_string(),
      Status::Closed => "⬜".to_string(),
      Status::Flagged => "".to_string(),
      Status::Opened(i) => MINE_CHAR[*i as usize].to_string()
  }}
}

impl AddAssign for Status {
  fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Self) {
    *self = match *self {
      Status::Opened(count) => match other {
        Status::Opened(count2) => Status::Opened(count + count2),
        _ => other,
      },
      _ => other
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What about using an enum like this instead?

```rs
enum Status {
    Closed,
    Flagged,
    Mined,
    Opened(u8),
}
```

However, I am a bit confused about how the mine state is held. I think it makes sense to use this when representing how mines should be displayed, but I see that you are also using this enum to hold the board state itself.

```rs
if mine_area[i+1][j+1] == CellStatus::MINED
```

I don't think this check makes sense because this enum is not suited for representing the state of the board; it's better for representing how the board should be drawn.

For example, a cell with a mine can be flagged or not flagged, but the enum can only represent one of these traits at a time.

Comment: I create 2 Vec<Vec<Status>>. One for drawing the game area, and the second for saving mines position. Maybe in the future, I'll create Vec<Point> where I will keep coord of mines and check the count of mines near like length of a vector.

Comment: Thanks for advice with Opened(u8), it's half of answer was))